# read all files in a subfolder python

Tags: python, directory

I have a folder structure as

```
>root
  > foldername1
    > subfoldername1
    > subfoldername2
    > subfoldername3
  > foldername2
    > subfoldername1
    > subfoldername2
    > subfoldername3
  > foldername3
    > subfoldername1
    > subfoldername2
    > subfoldername3
```

I would like to list all the file contained in the 'subfoldername3' of 'foldername2'

I approached the problem as follow, but since I have an incredible number of folders, subfolders, and files it takes forever to come to a conclusion.... is there a fastest way to do the same?

```
all_folders = [x[0] for x in walk(root)]
sub_folder = [s for s in all_folders if 'foldername2' in s]
matching_sub_path = [s for s in sub_folder if 'subfoldername3' in s]

matching_sub_path =
//root//foldername2//subfoldername3
```

Comment: if you know the folder name, directly use it in `os.listdir()`

Comment: I know that the root folder contains the string "foldername2" and that the subfolder contains the string "subfoldername3", but I am not sure of the entire names

Comment: @cdarke the file names

Comment: ok. Then your way is the right way. os.listdir will be faster.

Comment: Why don't you use `os.walk` ?

Comment: @ChatterOne I am using it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it since the `os.` part was missing. Then I don't think there is going to be a faster way/

Comment: have a look at [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) I believe it does what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: No, this is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think os.walk will list all directory recursively.

for you case try this if it suits your need.

```
all_folders = [x[0] for x in walk(root)]

all_files = [os.listdir(dir_path)
             for dir_pathin all_folder
                 if "subfoldername3" and "foldername2" in dir_path]
```